# python3.2 using subprocess.popen - need to format resulting stdout for writing to a file

Tags: python, python-3.2

I am using `subprocess` to run a command (from a spawned daemon) and trying to write results to a file.  The resulting string from `Popen` is `bytestring`.  How do I format this into something human readable before writing to a file?  using python3.2

have tried:

```
print (x,file=o)
f.write(str(rc.so))
print (str(rc.so) + "\n")
```

Nothing ends up looking readable ..

suspect code:

```
  rc = subprocess.Popen([cmd], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,   stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  x = rc.stdout.readlines()
  rc.so, rc.se = rc.communicate()
  with open(of,'w') as o, open(ef,'w') as e:
     print (str(rc.so) + "\n",file=o)
```

Comment: Have you tried decoding it? `your_string.decode('utf-8')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to decode it:

```
my_byte_string.decode('utf-8')
```

utf-8 might not be the best choice of decoding for your situation, it is one of a number of options available.

so that print statement should be more like:

```
print (rc.so.decode('utf-8') + "\n",file=o)
```

Comment: You may want `sys.getdefaultencoding()` instead of `utf-8` here. Assuming the other program is well-behaved, of course.